# LLVM/Clang 3.8 unresolved external symbol __readgsqword

Tags: windows, clang, llvm, unresolved-external

I'm trying to compile the following code in clang 3.8.0 for windows (pre-built)

```
int main()
{
    __readfsdword(0x30);
    __readgsqword(0x60);

    return 0;
}
```

and I'm getting the following link error

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __readgsqword referenced in
>   function main

any idea why the call to __readfsdword compiles and links fine but the call to __readgsqword does not?

I'm using the `-m64` compilation flag to build a 64bit binary, and `__x86_64__` preprocessor flag which should enable the use of __readgsqword according to `\lib\Headers\Intrin.h`

I get the same error on both x86 and x64 versions of clang.

any help will be appriciated

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved your problem, but I  will post an answer for future readers.

Just `#include <intrin.h>` in your project. No need to copy Clang's `Intrin.h`. Windows SDK provides that header.